# JsonFx Deserialize Special Characters

Tags: json, localization, jsonfx

I have a problem with deserializing special characters using Json.fx. When I try to serialize characters like "ğ,ş,ü", Jsonfx.Serialize and Jsonfx.Deserialize functions don't work correctly.

I try to solve Localization problem for my application. Help me please.

Here is my classes :

```
 public class Language
{
    public int LanguageId;
    public Menu menu;
    public Language()
    {
        menu = new Menu();
    }        
}

public class Menu
{
    public List<string> MenuStrings;

    public Menu()
    {
        MenuStrings = new List<string>();
    }
```

}

---

```
public class Localization : MonoBehaviour {
public TextAsset LanguageFile;
private List<Language> _languages ;

private void Awake()
{
        Language Example = new Language();
        Example.LanguageId = 7;
        Example.menu.MenuStrings.Add("İskeğderinoviş");
        Example.menu.MenuStrings.Add("ŞağmiI");
        Example.menu.MenuStrings.Add("Şjikovamoğviş");

        Debug.Log(JsonWriter.Serialize(Example));
}
```

Log Message :

> {"LanguageId":7,"menu":{"MenuStrings":["\u0130ske\u011Fderinovi\u015F","\u015Ea\u011FmiI","\u015Ejikovamo\u011Fvi\u015F"]}}
>   UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>   Localization:Awake() (at Assets/Scripts/Localization.cs:155)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It looks like it serialized it correctly. What were you expecting it to do? Those '\u0130' characters are unicode escape sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1077288/jsonfx-deserialize-special-characters.html

> What is incorrect? Json uses Unicode to encode non-ASCII characters. For example, \u011F is the encoding for ğ. It appears to be working correctly to me.
>
> Edit: Here are the syntax diagrams for Json:
>   http://www.json.org/fatfree.html. It appears that a JSON string can be
>   the actual Unicode letters, or the \uNNNN format. Why JsonFx is using
>   the latter I don't know. Maybe that's a setting?